# Missing text element in a formula

Tags: math-mode, equations

I want to display the following equation in Latex:

u=g(v,theta)

The code I'm using is:

```
\usepackage{graphicx, latexsym}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{getmod}    
\\text{u}=text{g}\text{v}, \theta),    
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

However, I get the following output:

[image: ![missing]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npnlu.png)

So, the u is missing and there's an addition to my equality sign...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `\begin{equation} u=g(v,\theta) \end{equation}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really *must* typeset the letters `u`, `g`, and `v` using upright ("roman") glyphs, you should write

```
\mathrm{u}=\mathrm{g}(\mathrm{v}, \theta)
```

Note that your code -- `\\text{u}=text{g}\text{v}, \theta)` -- contains three errors: double-backslash instead of single-backslash before the first instance of `text`, a missing (single) backslash before the second instance of `text`, and a missing `(` after `g`. Separately, while it's not technically an error to use `\text` in the present context, it's far better to use `\mathrm` here; that's why I use in the formula shown above.

That said, I really think you should employ math italics, i.e., write the equation as

```
u = g ( v, \theta)
```

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
% "latexsym" is deprecated, especially since you're loading "amssymb"
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{getmod}    
\mathrm{u}=\mathrm{g}(\mathrm{v}, \theta)   
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}   
u=g(v,\theta)    
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I can partially reproduce your output with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx, latexsym}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{getmod}
\u=g(v, \theta),
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

where the error is clearly `\u`.

Just type in naturally (and don't load `latexsym`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{getmod}
u=g(v, \theta),
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]